# why Gotham font in CSS is not working on firefox?

Tags: css, font-face, font-family

what i used in css is @font-face like below

```
   @font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham';

    src: url('../assets/fonts/Gotham Book.otf')format("opentype");
}

body {
background:transparent;
min-height:100%;    
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
line-height: 1.5em;
font-size:14px;
font-family: Gotham;
color:#fff;
color:rgba(255,255,255,.8); 
font-weight: normal;
```

}
 it works perfectly in chrome but fails in fire fox showing as times new roman . font gotham has been installed in the folder and link is just as given.

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in a code snippet ?

Comment: What does the browser console say? Look for 404 or CORS errors.

Comment: it just display times new roman font

Comment: Arivind S Sorry Sir I cant ! but if u guide me i will for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution for this is apply `.eot`, `.woff`, `.woff2` as you have done

Please refer below example.

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'co-text';
   src: url('CoText-Light.eot');
   src: url('CoText-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('CoText-Light.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('CoText-Light.woff') format('woff'),
       url('CoText-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
   font-weight: 300;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

Let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: add all font formats once and try again. not only .woff. For further inspect show your codes and root structure.

Comment: Thank you guys Problem is Solved